# How to get dynamic data from ADO.NET in while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, mono, npgsql

ASP.NET MVC4 application uses modified WebMatrix Dynamicrecord to get dynamic data from ADO.NET and show it in a WebGrid.

Running application causes strange exception

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

in method

```
private object GetNonNullValue(int i)
```

at line

```
var value = Record[i];
```

Using foreach as shown in comment does not work in Mono as discussed in https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/295 . So application uses while but while does not work in Windows also.

How to get dynamic data in while loop  ?

Whole solution is available at http://wikisend.com/download/360760/invalidattemptoreadwhennodataispresent.zip

Controller:

```
using Eeva.Business;
using Eeva.Erp.ViewModels;
using Npgsql;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Eeva.Erp.Controllers
{
    public class ReportController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            var data = TestData();
            return View("ReportData", new ReportDataViewModel(data, ""));
        }

        IEnumerable<dynamic> TestData()
        {
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
            {
                connection.Open();

                DbCommand command = (DbCommand)connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "select 'A' union select 'B'";

                using (command)
                {
                    using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = null;

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (columnNames == null)
                                columnNames = GetColumnNames(reader);
                            yield return new EevaDynamicRecord(columnNames, reader);
                        }
                        //foreach (DbDataRecord record in reader)
                        //{
                        //    if (columnNames == null)
                        //        columnNames = GetColumnNames(record);
                        //    yield return new EevaDynamicRecord(columnNames, record);
                        //}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames(IDataRecord record)
        {
            // Get all of the column names for this query
            for (int i = 0; i < record.FieldCount; i++)
                yield return record.GetName(i);
        }

        static string ConnectionString()
        {
            return new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                Host = "localhost",
                UserName = "postgres",
            }.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Eeva.Business;

namespace Eeva.Erp.ViewModels
{
    public class ReportDataViewModel 
    {
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> Rows { get; set; }

        public string Source;

        public ReportDataViewModel(IEnumerable<dynamic> rows, string source)
        {
            Rows = rows;
            Source = source;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Eeva.Erp.ViewModels.ReportDataViewModel
@using System.Web.Helpers

@{ Layout = null;
 var gd = new WebGrid(source: Model.Rows );
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    @gd.GetHtml()
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamicrecord is used from MVC4 source code with modifications:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WebMatrix.Data.Resources;

namespace Eeva.Business
{
    public sealed class EevaDynamicRecord : DynamicObject, ICustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        public EevaDynamicRecord(IEnumerable<string> columnNames, IDataRecord record)
        {
            Debug.Assert(record != null, "record should not be null");
            Debug.Assert(columnNames != null, "columnNames should not be null");

            Columns = columnNames.ToList();
            Record = record;
        }

        public IList<string> Columns { get; private set; }

        private IDataRecord Record { get; set; }

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Record.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string normname = Record.GetName(i);
                    if (normname.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        return GetNonNullValue(i);
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No column " + name);
            }
        }

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return GetNonNullValue(index); // GetValue(Record[index]);
            }
        }

        public string Field(int fldNo)
        {
            return Record.GetName(fldNo).ToUpperInvariant();
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = this[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }

        private object GetNonNullValue(int i)
        {
            var value = Record[i];
            if (DBNull.Value == value || value == null)
            {
                var tt = Record.GetFieldType(i).Name;
                switch (tt)
                {
                    case "Decimal":
                    case "Int32":
                    case "Double":
                        return 0;
                    case "String":
                        return "";

                    case "DateTime":
                        return null;

                    case "Boolean":
                        // kui seda pole, siis demos lao kartoteek kartoteegi kaart annab vea:
                        return false;

                }
                return null;
            }
            if (value is decimal? || value is decimal)
                return Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(double));

            if (value is string)
                return value.ToString().TrimEnd();
            return value;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
        {
            return Columns;
        }

        private void VerifyColumn(string name)
        {
            // REVIEW: Perf
            if (!Columns.Contains(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                  "Invalid Column Name " + name));
            }
        }

        AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
        {
            return AttributeCollection.Empty;
        }

        string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
        {
            return null;
        }

        string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
        {
            return null;
        }

        TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
        {
            return null;
        }

        EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
        {
            return null;
        }

        PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
        {
            return null;
        }

        object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
        {
            return null;
        }

        EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return EventDescriptorCollection.Empty;
        }

        EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
        {
            return EventDescriptorCollection.Empty;
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)this).GetProperties();
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
        {
            // Get the name and type for each column name
            var properties = from columnName in Columns
                             let columnIndex = Record.GetOrdinal(columnName)
                             let type = Record.GetFieldType(columnIndex)
                             select new DynamicPropertyDescriptor(columnName, type);

            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray(), readOnly: true);
        }

        object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
        {
            return this;
        }

        private class DynamicPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
        {
            private static readonly Attribute[] _empty = new Attribute[0];
            private readonly Type _type;

            public DynamicPropertyDescriptor(string name, Type type)
                : base(name, _empty)
            {
                _type = type;
            }

            public override Type ComponentType
            {
                get { return typeof(EevaDynamicRecord); }
            }

            public override bool IsReadOnly
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            public override Type PropertyType
            {
                get { return _type; }
            }

            public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
            {
                return false;
            }

            public override object GetValue(object component)
            {
                EevaDynamicRecord record = component as EevaDynamicRecord;
                // REVIEW: Should we throw if the wrong object was passed in?
                if (record != null)
                {
                    return record[Name];
                }
                return null;
            }

            public override void ResetValue(object component)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                  "DataResources.RecordIsReadOnly", Name));
            }

            public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                  "DataResources.RecordIsReadOnly", Name));
            }

            public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I posted this also in http://forums.asp.net/p/2013821/5795169.aspx

**Update**

Problably creating a copy of every dynamicrecord solves the issue:

```
Dictionary<string, object> Clonedict;
public EevaDynamicRecord Clone()
{
    var res = new EevaDynamicRecord(Columns, Record);
    res.Clonedict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Record.FieldCount; i++)
        res.Clonedict[Record.GetName(i)] = Record[i]);
    return res;
    // this also does not work:
    // return (EevaDynamicRecord)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Is there better solution ?

Comment: I notice that you're not validating that `i` is a valid column index in `GetNonNullValue` or in `this[int index]`.  Perhaps you're ending up using an out of range column number?

Comment: Debugger shows that i has value 0 . This is perfect value, result contains single column.

Comment: I've seen problems, not with this pattern, but with others, where a `DbCommand` and a `DbDataReader` were wrapped in a `using` clause and a `DbDataReader` was returned that was acted on after the `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` went out of scope.  It truncated the data.  Perhaps something like that is happening with your `yield`: your `DbDataReader` is detached from the source data by the time the `IEnumerable<dynamic>` gets enumerated.  Thus your `IDataRecord` is invalid by the time it gets accessed.

Comment: How to fix this so that it works in Mono also? If while is replaced with foreach as shown in comments after while, it works in .NET4 but not in Mono.

Comment: I've posted an answer which I hope will help.

Comment: I changed code according to answer but problem persists. Code in answer also reads all data to memory while code in question only returns required data. Maybe reader uses static buffer which is overwritten on each iteration. If end of data is received, buffer is invalidated and thus all references become invalid. It can solved by manually allocating value for every dynamicrecord instance. I wanted to know is there better solution.

Comment: I updated question and added possible solution. This is ugly, is there a better way?

Comment: This is just an thought, but maybe you could copy the data from the `IDataRecord` that you pass in to the constructor of `EevaDynamicRecord` to a `Dictionary` or something similar, and use that `Dictionary` as the value of `Record`?  Changing `Record`'s data type, of course.   Might be more elegant.

Comment: The code which I posted saves record values in Dictionary. DynamicRecord shoudl also changed so that it returns value from this Clonedict. I dont understand your comment, how to simplify it. It looks like Clone method does this as you described, do you recommend to move this method code to constructor ? Is this npgsql issue or will other ADO.NET providers have same issue ?

Comment: I was recommending moving the method code to the constructor because I thought it would be more elegant that way. You were complaining that your Clone code was ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know that this will necessarily work, but to suggest it I needed to post an answer since it includes a code sample.

If I'm right and the problem is occurring because you're attempting to access data from a reader after the command has gone out of scope, this will work around that.

Replace your `Test` method with this:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var data = TestData().ToArray();
        return View("ReportData", new ReportDataViewModel(data, ""));
    }
```

If that doesn't help, try replacing the `TestData` method with this:

```
    IEnumerable<dynamic> TestData()
    {
        List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>();
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            DbCommand command = (DbCommand)connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select 'A' union select 'B'";

            using (command)
            {
                using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = null;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (columnNames == null)
                            columnNames = GetColumnNames(reader);
                        results.Add(new EevaDynamicRecord(columnNames, reader));
                    }
                    //foreach (DbDataRecord record in reader)
                    //{
                    //    if (columnNames == null)
                    //        columnNames = GetColumnNames(record);
                    //    yield return new EevaDynamicRecord(columnNames, record);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Number of rows in actual result is huge. WebGrid show only first page in this case. Your code reads all rows. This is very slow and result does not fit to memory. How to fix this ?

Comment: I applied both changes to test code but problem persists.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try.  I didn't realize your data set would be so huge.